# Finding gaps/idle times in an array of login/logout data

Tags: ios, algorithm

I have a JSON Object with an array of "employee" objects that indicate a login and logout time for each individual employee. I'm trying to write a function in Swift to show me the times when there are no employees logged in (i.e. the idle or gap time). Additionally this store has a set open/close time so I have the upper and lower bounds of when people could possibly be logged in.

I'm stuck on where to start so any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked through a number of well known algorithms, but can't seem to find anything. Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: please consider adding what you have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should review the help pages and review the section on asking good questions. Currently your question is far too vague and broad. [Edit] your question to include details about your current data structures, what research you have attempted, code you have attempted, and clear details about you actually need help with.

Comment: First of all, I would convert the complicated time structure into a Long, so that every interval is represented by two (pretty big) numbers. To simplify it further, I would divide it to the needed precision (probably minutes). Then, maybe, I would subtract to a reasonable start, perhaps if it is for a single day, such that 60*24 is the maximum.

Comment: I would then draw a list of intervals, ordered by starttime, with overlaps and gaps, about 10 intervals. Represent them as pairs of numbers (1,5), (2,3), (4,8) ... . Then shuffle the pairs and take it to test your algorithm, which might, for instance, start with ordering the List first. :)

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is pretty simple. I'll assume that you can identify a starting place where nobody is logged in, and that your input data is sorted by ascending time.

Build an empty dictionary, keyed by login name. Then start reading the log. When you get a login, add that login name to the dictionary. When you get a logout, remove that login name to the dictionary. Whenever you add a name to an empty dictionary, you've ended an idle period. Whenever removing a name causes the dictionary to be empty, you start an idle period.

Pseudo code is:

```
names = empty dictionary

while not end of log
     if login-type is login
         if names contains login-name
             // error: already logged in
         if names.count == 0
             // end of an idle period
             idle-end = login-time
         names.add(login-name)
     else if login-type is logout
         if names does not contain login-name
             // error: logout without login
         names.remove(login-name)
         if names.count == 0
             // beginning of an idle period
             idle-start = login-time
end while
```

You'll need some additional logic to empty the dictionary at the end of each open period, and allow for early logins (before the official open). But the basic idea above should give you a good start on the project.